# "When I say...I mean" or "When I said...I meant"

Tags: grammar

context:

> I live in a small town called Jiaxing. It is one-hour's drive away from Shanghai. When I say small, I mean it is small by Chinese standard——there is close to a million people living there...

In the above sentence, should I use *I say* or *I said*? Gramatically, it seems to me the past tense is correct, but intuitively, the present tense sounds better.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: In this sense "say" would be appropriate if it was just said, in the current conversation, while "said" would be used if it was said some time in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to stay in the present tense since you are in the act of narrating in the present rather than referring to something said in the past.

Unrelated, but it should be "There **are** close to a million people..."